# Setting interval value for UISlider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

I need to set the interval value for an UISlider.
Please help..

Answer (score 13):

`yourSlider.value = x;`

You should really read the documentation, lots of great resources in the [iOS Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

**Edit: With regards to your more specific question in the comments:**

```
yourSlider.minimumValue = -10;
yourSlider.maximumValue = 10;
[yourSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(roundValue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)roundValue{
    yourSlider.value = round(yourSlider.value);
}
```

Comment: ohh is that so..

I know how to set the value..
I need to set the increment interval ..
Meaning if slider ranges from -10 to 10.. n I want the increment interval to be 0.5... then how do I set the interval..

Comment: On `UIControlEvenValueChanged` you round the slider.value.

Comment: Mike, thanks dat was useful..
The slider is now incrementing with the required interval, but there is a jerk with the slider ball all time.. :(

Comment: I'm very confused as to what it is you're trying to do exactly. If you want the slider to be smooth but only return rounded results, just use `round(yourSlider.value)` and skip all the rest.

Comment: Wow, this solution simply crashes for me. terminates with uncaught exception. Think it is the event handler needs an (id) sender argument ...yup, change `- (void)roundValue{` to `- (void)roundValue:(id)sender{`

Answer (score 4):

A flexible solution:

```
    // define MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE and INTERVAL somewhere, such as 3, 18 and 3

    slider.TouchUpInside += delegate {
        touchUpInside();
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// set value to one of intervals
    /// </summary>
    void touchUpInside(){

        // get the nearest interval value
        for(int i=MIN_VALUE; i<=MAX_VALUE; i=i+INVERVAL){

            if(slider.Value > i && slider.Value < i + INVERVAL){
                if(slider.Value - i < i + INVERVAL - slider.Value){
                    slider.Value = i;
                }else{
                    slider.Value = i + INVERVAL;
                }

                break;
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: thankx Genc it really work for me. You just save my lot of time :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old but I just want to share how I did this.

Assuming that the UISlider object has already been initialized, first, the minimum and maximum values of the UISlider object must be set:

```
mySlider.minimumValue = -2.0;
mySlider.maximumValue = 2.0;
```

Then, set the selector that will handle the changes in the slider:

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidChangeValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Also, set the interval (to a property). It is important that the interval is positive. (And, really, the INTERVAL MUST BE POSITIVE.)

```
self.interval = 0.5 //_interval is float
```

Declare the method(s):

```
- (void)sliderDidChangeValue:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;

    //Round the value to the a target interval
    CGFloat roundedValue = [self roundValue:slider.value];

    //Snap to the final value
    [slider setValue:roundedValue animated:NO];
}

- (float)roundValue:(float)value
{
    //get the remainder of value/interval
    //make sure that the remainder is positive by getting its absolute value
    float tempValue = fabsf(fmodf(value, _interval)); //need to import <math.h>

    //if the remainder is greater than or equal to the half of the interval then return the higher interval
    //otherwise, return the lower interval
    if(tempValue >= (_interval / 2.0)){
        return value - tempValue + _interval;
    }
    else{
        return value - tempValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int sliderValue =  kSliderInterval * floor((slider.value / kSliderInterval) + 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

`UISliders` do not 'increment' their value, they increase or decrease their value according to how they're touched. You can use these properties to set the slider limits:

```
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest is that put the level just below the slider where you want to put value and set maximum and minimum value then the in between value can be calculated by no of point and by division and finally display in uilabel the values.
hope this will help

good luck