# Objective C / iPhone - how to bind UISlider to code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, uislider

I'm just starting with Objective C, but I'm already running into a problem:
When I did this in the past, I had no problem with it:
I made a new UISlider, clicked it, CTRL dragged a blue line to the code, and somehow I was then able to read it's values.

However, I am now running into the problem that I can't draw those lines anymore.
By messing around I managed to get buttons to work, but the slider just won't work.
my Mainwindow.xib has got the iSaturateViewController class,
iSaturateViewController.xib has got the whole interface in it.

How can I get the UISlider to work without being able to draw that line?

How I have it now:
(in iSaturateViewController.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface iSaturateViewController : UIViewController {
    UISlider * satSlider;
    UILabel * satLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider * satSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel * satLabel;

-(IBAction) changeSaturation:(id) sender;

@end
```

(in iSaturateViewController.m):

```
@synthesize satLabel,satSlider;

-(IBAction) changeSaturation:(id)sender {
    satLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Saturation:  %d ", (Float32)satSlider.value];
     NSLog(@"%f", satSlider.value);
}
```

Ath the moment the NSLog shows: 0.00000000

Also, I've set the Label in the Identity properties to: satSlider (slider) and satLabel (label).

**Just to clarify my goal:**

I want the slider's (satSlider) value to show in the UILabel (satLabel) via the function changeSaturation.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Why do you mention C#?  Do you mean Objective-C?

Comment: When you say "C#", what do you actually mean? Objective-C? Cocoa? You clearly don't mean [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: Whoops, sorry for that. I indeed meant Objective C. I thought that was the short way of writing Objective C... is there another short way to write Objective C?

Answer (score 6):

Add the method declaration:

```
-(IBAction) changeSaturation:(id)sender;
```

to the header file iSaturateViewController.h

Then, assign the *Value Changed* action of your UISlider to your *changeSaturation* method. Right click on the slider and drag the *Value Changed* to the *File's Owner* and connect them. It should work.

You can also try this:

```
-(IBAction)changeSaturation:(id)sender {

     UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
     satLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Saturation: %f", slider.value];
     NSLog(@"Saturation: %f", slider.value);
}
```

Regarding UILabel - add IBOutlet and connect it in the Interface Builder. The interface should be like that:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface iSaturateViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UISlider * satSlider;
    IBOutlet UILabel * satLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider * satSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * satLabel;

-(IBAction) changeSaturation:(id) sender;

@end
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got that working now, however, the value returned in the NSLog is still 0.0000000, and the text in the UILabel wont change...

Comment: The code executes just fine, but the value returns 0.0000000 and the label wont change :S

Comment: Ah thank you so very much! The slider finally outputs proper data... However... the UILabel still won't change... Do I have to connect it to something aswell?

Comment: Yes, you nedd to connect the Label as well. I updated the answer. You need to add the IBOutlet keyword and connect the label with an outlet in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Yeah... That's kinda where the problem comes in: I can't connect it in the Interface Builder... When I view the XIB file and switch to the mode with the suit on the button [whatever thats called], and have the selection set to Automatic, the right area is empty... When I switch to Manual and open the ViewController.h file, I still cant draw a line...

Comment: You can do this another way, click on your XIB, on the right side select on the label end right click. Click the New referencing outlet (or sth like that) and drag it to your File's Owner. You should be able to link it to your label in code. If not remember to add an IBOutlet keyword before the UILabel in the header file.

Comment: The main XIB or the other one? From the other one I cant connect a referencing outlet to anything... When I do it from the main, I get the UIApplication as IBOutlet :/

also, this is code from my main xib:
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class iSaturateViewController;

@interface iSaturateAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    iSaturateViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet iSaturateViewController *viewController;

@end

`

Comment: Not the main xib but the iSaturateViewController xib (the one where you have your UILabel).

Comment: From there, I can't connect anything to code..., like I said: automatically the right window is empty, and when setting the .h file there still keeps me from connecting anything...

Comment: I think you didn't set your outlets correctly in the interface. That is why they do not appear when you are trying to connect them. I updated my answer. If it does not help then I surrender :)

Comment: Hmmm, I have my code like you have right now... though... still no changing label :( Could it be that I need to set some special options? I also noticed that the Label DOES indeed show up on the side, in the objects list: http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/2969/screenshot20111213at254.png
I've had this working in another app before, It's really weird it's not working now... Could it perhaps do harm if I would remove the Mainwindow.xib and rename the iSaturateViewController.xib to MainWindow.xib?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the key thing you’re missing is that the `satSlider` outlet isn’t hooked up, so its value is `nil`. You connected the slider’s action to the `-changeSaturation:` method, but it sounds like you didn’t also connect the `satSlider` property to the slider itself. Sending a message (like `value` in this case) to `nil` doesn’t do anything, and returns 0, so 0 is the value you’re getting out of it. Hook up your outlet by Ctrl-dragging from the property in the code to the slider in your UI and it should work.

Comment: The problem is: I can't. When I view the XIB file and switch to the mode with the suit on the button [whatever thats called], and have the selection set to Automatic, the right area is empty...
When I switch to Manual and open the ViewController.h file, I still cant draw a line...

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your header and add the method declaration. Then in IB, associate the first responder for value changed to the UISlider. Also slider.value, you need to read article: [Setting interval value for UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617628/setting-interval-value-for-uislider)

Comment: Updated the start post to show the IBAction. Though what do you mean by associate the first responder?

Comment: EDIT: haha, I looked the Sent Events, and I now know what you mean. Same as @Rafał Sroka said