# Programming a UISlider with "hard-stops"

Tags: ios, uislider

I have a `UISlider` with 6 "divisions" I want the slider to have a sort of hard-stop at each division instead of just stopping anywhere when it's being slid around. I don't see a way of doing this in my `Main.Storyboard`. Is there a way?

Comment: If they are evenly spaced, you can use: `slider.value = ((float)((int)((slider.value + 0.5) * 6.0))) / 6.0;` in the `sliderValueChanged:` method.

Comment: I just shared my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617628/setting-interval-value-for-uislider/20398854#20398854

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this in code. Setup a method that will be called when the slider's value is changed. Then in the implementation of that method you can do something like this:

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    if (slider.value >= 0.46 && slider.value <= 0.54) {
        slider.value = 0.5;
    }
}
```

This will give the slider the appearance of a "detent" in the middle. For your slider you need to check five different ranges to break the slider up into 6 divisions.