# Setting the values of uislider in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I want to set the value of my uislider like this (4.8,4.9,4.10,4.11,5.0,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9,5.10,5.11,6.0,6.1,6.2,6.3) but don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me with this? I even don't know how to code this. I only created the outlet of uislider.

Comment: set minimum value 4.8 and maximum value 6.3

Comment: Do you mean that you want to move the slider and get a value from these, e.g. 4.8 for lowest slider value to 6.3 at highest?

Comment: yes, lowest is 4.8 and highest is 6.3

Comment: you can start here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/minimumValue and tell us what you don't understand

Comment: study this http://codewithchris.com/uislider-tutorial-ios-slider/

Comment: thanks for the help.
but this does not let me enter the value 4.10, 4.11, 5.10, 5.11

Comment: I need these values too because it's the height paramater.

Comment: Also can  take help from http://www.xprogress.com/post-35-uislider-tutorial-example-how-to-use-slider-in-iphone-sdk-xcode/

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20398854/5060335) will solve your exact issue.

Answer (score -1):

you can set slidervalue like,

`self.mySlider.minimumValue = 4.8;`

`selfmySlider.maximumValue = 6.8;`

`self.mySlider.value = 5.8;`  //cuerrent value

if you change above value (as per question) then you can shedule timer `(NSTimer)` and in selector method of this timer you can change slidervalue according to your value array that posted in question.

**Update as per comment :**

```
 NSTimer * sliderTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 int counter = 0; take counter to differentiate object.
 NSArray *arr = []; //this is your value arr according to question
```

then in your update slider method update your slider smething like,

```
- (void)updateSlider{

   mySlider.value = [[arr objectAtIndex:counter] floatValue];
   counter ++;

   }
```

Something lie this, manage according to  your context. this is example. and please avoid syntax mistake if any.
Hope this will help :)

Comment: if you think it is helpful then accept and upvote the answer so other people with similar issue can use it :)

Comment: @Lion - I m not assign the negative vote, congratz for try